# Conda environment in VSCode has to be restarted to show correct packages

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, anaconda, conda, miniconda

When starting vscode from the terminal with a conda environment active, the integrated terminal will show all of my packages from my system python when using `pip list`, even though `conda info --envs` shows that the correct environment is active. I am on MacOS Sonoma 14.3 if that is important.

Starting from my terminal, I activate the environment, check packages, and launch vscode.

[image: terminal window]

In the integrated terminal, it seems to be active, but wrong packages showing

[image: integrated vscode terminal]

But if I deactivate the environment and then immediately reactivate, it shows the correct packages.
[image: integrated vscode terminal after reset]

If I kill the integrated terminal and restart it, it goes back to showing the incorrect packages. I would appreciate any help.